# constructor with parameters in a signalr-core hub

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-signalr

I would like to inject something into my hub.

Basically I am trying to the equivalent of this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/advanced/dependency-injection, but for SignalR-Core.
I am mostly interested in the part

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.Register(
        typeof(ChatHub), 
        () => new ChatHub(new ChatMessageRepository()));

    App.MapSignalR();

    // ...
}
```

How do I do this Net Core and SignalR-Core?

Comment: Did you already try something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Register your `ChatMessageRepository` in the DI container with:

```
services.AddTransient(typeof(ChatMessageRepository), typeof(ChatMessageRepository));
```

and then inject into your hub in the ctor:

```
public ChatHub : Hub
{
    private readonly ChatMessageRepository _repository;
    public ChatHub(ChatMessageRepository repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: you do realize that doing it this way completely breaks signalr since it is dependent on parameterless constructors for its hubs? I think there could be some setting like the old GlobalHost that you can modify in the Startup class that solves this.

Comment: Have you tried that? Did you look at some samples e.g.: https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/blob/dev/samples/ChatSample/Hubs/Chat.cs#L12. SignalR core is using built-in activation that can inject parameters. https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/blob/5dceaa81499c43afcad06349ad3fdda0feb92d84/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Core/DefaultHubActivator.cs from the DI

Comment: @Pawel is correct. The new SignalR is DI aware and doing the above works. A simpler version is `services.AddTransient<ChatMessageRepository>();`