# Access Cloudscribe SiteID outside Controller or Views

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-signalr, cloudscribe

I have a `class` which I want to get the Cloudscribe `SiteId` but I am unsure how to access it.

If I was using a `controller` then I would be able to rely on the `SiteContext` to be DI'd into the constructor but that does not work in this instance.

Can someone tell me how I can access the `SiteId` property in the code below?

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CoLabR
{
    public class Messaging : Hub
    {
        private string _siteId;

        public Messaging()
        {
            //Code here to get SiteID
            _siteId = "<<Code for getting Site ID";
        }

        public Task Post(string message)
        {

            return Clients.Group(_siteId).InvokeAsync("Post", message);
        }

        public Task JoinRoom()
        {
            Groups.AddAsync(Context.ConnectionId, _siteId);
            return Clients.Group(_siteId).InvokeAsync("Post", Context.User.Identity.Name + " joined. " + _siteId);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

SignalR Core supports injecting into hubs so you should be able to just inject `SiteContext` into `Messaging`. 
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46406269/constructor-with-parameters-in-a-signalr-core-hub) is a related question that shows how to do that.

Comment: Thanks @Pawel I wrongly assumed because the SiteContext could already be injected into the controllers on the site it would also work for my Hub, but it looks like I needed to explicitly reference it in my `startup.cs`

Answer (score 0):

Although the answer from @Pawel helped me, my final solution differed. I tried registering `SiteContext` in my `Startup.cs` and injecting `SiteContext` into my constructor for the Hub but it kept returning a different SiteID on each page load (or if I used Singleton it gave me the same SiteId across multiple CloudScribe Sites).

In the end my solution was to change the Hub constructor to the below code

```
    public Messaging(SiteUserManager<SiteUser> userManager)
    {
        //Code here to get SiteID
        _siteId = userManager.Site.Id.ToString();
    }
```

This gave me a consistent SiteId for each Tenant site in my application.